# Flask - CGI - need to fix issues with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, flask, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have successfully deployed a Flask app using CGI. In order to get the app working, my .htaccess file had to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/user/public_html/mysite/cgi-bin/main.cgi/$1 [L]
```

However, I am facing a couple of issues.

1. mysite.com works, but when I link other pages to the home page, it takes them to mysite.com/cgi-bin/main.cgi. I'd like for the links to take users to mysite.com. Similarly, when I try to link to another page, it goes to mysite.com/cgi-bin/main.cgi/page2, when I actually want it to be mysite.com/page2. How can I fix this?
2. The following .htaccess content seems to not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

I'm not sure if the above two issues are related, but I'd like to fix both.

Comment: For `it takes them to mysite.com/cgi-bin/main.cgi. I'd like for the links to take users to mysite.com. Similarly, when I try to link to another page, it goes to mysite.com/cgi-bin/main.cgi/page2, when I actually want it to be mysite.com/page2` Could you please post more clearly like which page you are hitting? And to which page you want to redirect? For example: You are hitting `http://localhost:80/test` and you want it to redirect to `http://localhost:80/testnew` etc?

Comment: I'm hitting mysite.com/cgi-bin/main.cgi and I want to redirect to simply mysite.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following Rules. Please make sure your htaccess Rules file is besides your cgi-bin directory/folder. Also clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for applying https to urls.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

##Rules to remove www from urls.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1/%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/main.cgi/page2/?$ cgi-bin/templates/page2/index.html [NC,L]
```

JS/CS rewrite/redirect:

You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.